# Оформление несобственно-прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

Очень часто в книгах встречается странное оформление прямой речи без кавычек, когда автор использует аргумент "это несобственно-прямая речь". Например: Мы бы пошли туда, думал он, если бы захотели, конечно.
Как я понимаю, несобственно-прямая речь исключает присутствие вводящих слов (слов автора). К тому же в предложении создается абсолютнейшая путаница, когда потеряны границы конкретного высказывания. Подскажите, неужели это тенденция в языке такая или я в корне ошибаюсь? Как может несобственно-прямая речь оставаться таковой, если присутствует указание на то, что она принадлежит персонажу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Мы бы пошли туда, думал он, если бы захотели, конечно.*

Вы правы, я тоже считаю, что это обычное оформление прямой речи, разрываемой словами автора.

Стилистический энциклопедический словарь русского языка толкует  термин  **несобственно-прямая, или несобственно-авторская, речь**  так:
Несобственно-прямая, или несобственно-авторская, речь -

> это **речь повествователя, пронизанная вместе с тем лексикой, значениями
>   (семантикой), синтаксическими конструкциями речи персонажа – источника
>   информации, его интонациями, чувствами, мыслями.** С прямой речью ее
>   сближает воспроизведение манеры речи говорящего (его подлинных
>   выражений, строя речи), с косвенной речью – то, что в ней личные формы
>   глаголов и местоимений употреблены от лица повествователя. Но при этом
>   не используются никакие вводящие глаголы речи и мысли ("говорил,
>   что…"; "сообщил, что…"), т.е. отсутствует формальный сигнал перехода
>   от авторской речи к чужой. Н.-п. р. не выделяется в тексте авторскими
>   словами, не вводится как придаточная часть сложноподчиненного
>   предложения. Автор как бы сливает речь своего героя со своей,
>   приспосабливает собственную манеру говорить к его речевой манере.
>   Напр.: Он вспомнил, как в детстве во время грозы он с непокрытой
>   головой выбегал в сад, а за ним гнались две беловолосые девочки с
>   голубыми глазами и их мочил дождь; они хохотали от восторга, но когда
>   раздавался сильный удар грома, девочки доверчиво прижимались к
>   мальчику, он крестился и спешил читать: "Свят, свят, свят…". О, куда
>   вы ушли, в каком вы море утонули, зачатки прекрасной, чистой жизни?
>   Грозы уж он не боится и природы не любит, бога у него нет, все
>   доверчивые девочки, каких он знал когда-либо, уже сгублены им и его
>   сверстниками, в родном саду он за всю свою жизнь не посадил ни одного
>   деревца и не вырастил ни одной травки, а живя среди живых, не спас ни
>   одной мухи, а только разрушал, губил и лгал, лгал… (А. Чехов.). К
>   Н.-п. р., как правило, прибегают для передачи невысказанных мыслей,
>   внутреннего монолога. Создается двуплановость высказывания:
>   воспроизводится "внутренняя речь" героя, но выступает за него автор:
>   *Она выписывала книги и журналы и читала у себя в комнате.И по ночам
>   читала, лежа в постели. Когда часы в коридоре били два или три и когда
>   уже от чтения начинали болеть виски, она садилась в постели и думала.
>   *Что делать? Куда деваться? Проклятый, назойливый вопрос, на который
>   давно уже готово много ответов и в сущности нет ни одного. О, как это,
>   должно быть, благородно, свято, картинно – служить народу, облегчать
>   его муки, просвещать его. Но она, Вера, не знает народа. И как подойти
>   к нему? Он чужд ей, неинтересен, она не выносит тяжелого запаха изб,
>   кабацкой брани, немытых детей, бабьих разговоров о болезнях** (А.
>   Чехов). Наиболее характерный тип несобственно-прямой речи –
>   вопросительные и восклицательные предложения, выделяющиеся на фоне
>   авторского повествования, например: *Он ужаснулся и в отчаянии
>   спрашивал себя, как это и зачем попал он в неизвестную землю, в
>   компанию страшных мужиков? Где теперь дядя, отец Христофор и Дениска?
>   Отчего они так долго не едут? Не забыли ли о нем?* (А. Чехов); *Николай
>   Ростов отвернулся и, как будто отыскивая чего-то, стал смотреть на
>   даль, на воду Дуная, на небо, на солнце. Как хорошо показалось небо,
>   как голубо, спокойно и глубоко! Как ярко и торжественно опускающееся
>   солнце! Как ласково и глянцевито блестела вода в далеком Дунае! (Л.
>   Толстой).* Н.-п. р. используется многими писателями. Сергей Залыгин,
>   автор "На Иртыше" и "Соленой пади", отмечал, что персонажи этих
>   произведений (Чаузов и Мещеряков) "буквально заставляли <…> писать о
>   них тем языком, который они считали приемлемым для себя <…> Конечно,
>   этот язык оставался в то же время и моим, он лежал в пределах моих
>   собственных возможностей, но эти собственные возможности как раз
>   они-то и расширяли" (Залыгин С., 1969, с. 120–121). По словам М.
>   Бахтина, Н.-п. р. является "наиболее важным и синтаксически
>   шаблонизированным <…> случаем интерферирующего слияния двух,
>   интонационно разнонаправленных речей", проявлением речевой
>   интерференции в языке.

https://stylistics.academic.ru/91/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-

Ничего общего с такой речью здесь нет, тем более, что и эмоций-то никаких нет, да и особенностей речи героя тоже.