# О правильном оформлении прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

При просмотре темы о несобственно-прямой речи мне встретился вопрос с нашего форума  с таким предложением: ***Мы бы пошли туда, думал он, если бы захотели, конечно.***

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457771/Оформление-несобственно-прямой-речи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457771/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8)

Оценка была такая: Вы правы, я тоже считаю, что это обычное оформление прямой речи, разрываемой словами автора.

Но мне кажется, что это предложение оформлено неправильно. А вы как думаете?

В современных текстах часто встречаются подобные случаи, но они вопросов не вызывают, например: "Неужели всё это в самом деле можно прочитать по глазам, думал потрясенный Ластик. Ясновидящий он, что ли?" (Б. Акунин)

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как это часто бывает, для ответа на вопрос недостаточно контекста. Если это отдельный абзац в книге, тогда, конечно, это неправильно оформленная прямая речь. Но если это авторский текст, в который необходимо включить мысль героя, тогда это один из приёмов так называемой необозначенной прямой речи и вопрос нужно ставить не о правильности или неправильности оформления, а об уместности или неуместности использования такого приёма.

Авторский текст в художественном произведении тесно переплетается с прямой речью героев, вплоть до полного их смешения. И цель хорошего автора состоит в том, чтобы показать читателю события с нужного в данный момент ракурса. Достижение этой цели не всегда возможно в рамках догматического деления только на прямую, несобственно-прямую и косвенную речь. Теоретики языка вводят ещё с десяток промежуточных и уточняющих терминов, для расшифровки которых им требуются десятки или сотни страниц монографий.

Если говорить о необозначенной прямой речи, то потребность в ней возникает чаще всего во внутренних монологах (героев или автора), в которых нужно показать читателю ситуацию с точки зрения другого человека. Приведу пару примеров.

> Трактирщик сказал, что не дам вам есть, пока не заплатите за прежнее.
> (Н.В. Гоголь)

Это называется "полупрямая речь". Такая конструкция для современного языка ненормативна. Но этим искуссным приёмом Гоголь переключает читателя с точки зрения Осипа на точку зрения трактирщика.

> В дремоту тяжко погружен,
> Он льет мучительные слезы,
> В волненьи мыслит: это сон!
> (А.С. Пушкин)

Пушкин описывает тревожный сон Руслана возле околдованной Людмилы. Описывает со стороны — с точки зрения автора. И при любом другом оформлении концовки возможность читателя отождествить себя с главным героем была бы здесь потеряна.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Я пишу комментарий в книжном стиле, это дискуссия, наши точки зрения могут не совпадать.  Но при   этом большое  спасибо вам за ответ,  я  действительно  очень благодарна,  а то все опять молчат!

***Мы бы пошли туда, думал он, если бы захотели, конечно.***

1. Я смотрела на это предложение и думала, что ему очень не хватает кавычек и тире. Его надо записать так: *«Мы бы пошли туда, – думал он, –  если бы захотели, конечно».*  Или так:  *Мы бы пошли туда,  думал я, если бы захотели, конечно.* (Здесь повествование от первого лица.)

Но внизу было  написано: это **обычное оформление прямой речи**, разрываемой словами автора.  И никто не возразил, все же видели.

Значит, я не знаю правил обычного оформления прямой речи, что же еще?  Как там сказал недавно один из участников  нашего форума?  «Это предложение ввело меня в ступор». Очень похожее состояние, кажется, оно еще называется **«когнитивный диссонанс».**

2. Итак,  это  **один из приёмов** так называемой «необозначенной прямой речи»?  Я против этого термина, но есть другой, очень похожий  – несобственно-прямая речь. Но это же не означает, что надо вообще **отменить все графические правила** оформления  прямой речи, если автору очень нужно слиться с мыслями героев. На письме  у него это, может, и получится, а **в устной речи как же**?
3. Нет,  **у Пушкина всё иначе**, там всё по правилам.  У него синтаксис другой, лексика  дословная, но  **правила для личных местоимений** он не нарушает. *«Он льет мучительные слезы, В волненьи мыслит: это сон!»*  Но это же БСП, и местоимений там нет.

Вот и в современном примере, который я  привожу, **местоимений тоже нет**.

4. **А в «Ревизоре»?** Там Осип два раза произносит  похожую фразу, но во втором случае она правильно оформлена.

(1) Вот теперь трактирщик сказал, **что  не дам вам** есть, пока не заплатите за прежнее; ну, а коли не заплатим?

(2) Да так; все равно, хоть и пойду, ничего из этого не будет. Хозяин сказал, **что больше не даст** обедать.

А может быть, в первом случае надо просто **кавычки** поставить, такое цитирование вроде бы возможно: *Вот теперь трактирщик сказал, что  **«не дам вам есть, пока не заплатите за прежнее»**; ну, а коли не заплатим?*

5. И  дальше там,  как мне кажется, тоже  **неверное оформление прямой речи**:

**Осип.** «Еще, **говорит**, и к городничему пойду; третью неделю барин денег не плотит. Вы-де с барином, **говорит**, мошенники, и барин твой — плут. Мы-де, **говорят**, этаких шерамыжников и подлецов видали».

**Зачем здесь кавычки,** по Розенталю они не нужны. В Правилах  вообще  довольно четко указано, когда можно не ставить кавычки (примечания, п.3) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158
3) если в середину прямой речи вставлен глагол говорит, играющий роль вводного слова, указывающего на источник сообщения: Умру, говорит, и слава Богу, говорит; не желаю, говорит, жить (Т.);

Вот такие «семинары» получаются по теме всего лишь одного предложения.
**Конец, а кто слушал – молодец!**

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [здесь](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/priemy-subektivatsii-v-sovremennoy-proze-yavleniya-modifikatsii), чем отличается необозначенная прямая речь от несобственно-прямой. Там поясняется с примерами. Жаль, не могу найти книгу Кожевниковой, где это объясняется как раз на примере цитаты Л.Толстого ("Глядя на знамя..."). Если наберёте в гугло-книгах так: **"Глядя на знамя" кожевникова толстой** (с кавычками), увидите небольшой фрагмент книги. Может, пример из Пушкина не совсем удачный, но вот цитату из Гоголя приводят и анализируют все авторы, изучающие прямую речь.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, обязательно посмотрю. Но мне хотелось бы услышать ваше личное мнение именно по приведенному предложению. Значит, с ним всё в порядке, я напрасно беспокоюсь? В каких-то случаях его можно оставить в ТАКОМ виде?! Тогда я действительно не разбираюсь в теме обычного оформления предложений с прямой речью. Пока оно у меня вызывает только  резкое НЕПРИЯТИЕ. Хорошо бы у классиков увидеть нечто подобное, а то у меня большого доверия к нашим литературоведам нет.  Вот лингвистов-грамматиков я уважаю (они имеют дело с точной наукой), а там кто кого переговорит, какие у них критерии!

Comment: Моё мнение: при вклинивании чужой речи в авторский текст (типа внутреннего монолога) такое оформление я вполне допускаю. Особенно если оно будет способствовать лучшему восприятию художественного замысла. Я не вижу, чем это принципиально хуже обсуждаемых примеров Л.Толстого и Н.В. Гоголя. До работ Бахтина некоторые корректоры правили Л.Толстого (ставили кавычки), а потом этот приём стали хвалить и приводить в пример другим. Неужели язык от этого стал хуже?

Comment: Думаю, в вопросах оформления лучше ориентироваться на эстетику литературоведов, а не на формализм лингвистов. Впрочем, я на своём мнении не настаиваю.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за ваше мнение, но я, сожалению, придерживаюсь другой точки зрения. Мне такая эстетика кажется письменно-графической  и поэтому не истинной,  а мнимой.  Она ближе не к художественному методу, а к неграмотному письму (пожалуйста, извините меня за резкость суждения). Кроме того, она в принципе расшатывает классическую систему письма, с этой точки зрения такому приему тоже надо дать оценку. А вот интересно, вам самим приходилось писать что-нибудь художественное? Странный вопрос, не правда ли? Но я почему-то об этом подумала, прочитав ваш комментарий.

Comment: Нет, Sharon, художественное я писать не умею. И я не вижу ничего плохого в том, что наши взгляды расходятся. Без столкновения мнений не может быть развития. Помнится, в каких-то других вопросах было наоборот: я предпочитаю придерживаться существующих традиций, а Вы желаете их изменить.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за дискуссию.  Тогда я вам посвящаю  монолог-пародию "Осип".

Answer (score 1):

***Мы** бы пошли туда, думал **он,** если бы захотели, конечно.*

Правильно ли оформлено это предложение?

Его, вероятно,  надо записать так: *«**Мы** бы пошли туда, – думал **он**, – если бы захотели, конечно»*. Или так: ***Мы** бы пошли туда, думал **я**, если бы захотели, конечно.* (Здесь повествование от первого лица.)

**О личных местоимениях** (для справок)

В косвенной речи слова говорящего претерпевают изменения: все **личные местоимения** употребляются с точки зрения **автора** пересказа;
https://ibrain.kz/russkiy-yazyk/pryamaya-i-kosvennaya-rech

**МОНОЛОГ ОСИПА (ПАРОДИЯ)**

Молчит Форум… Может, времени у людей нет, да только на другие вопросы у них времени хватает, отвечают охотно. Значит, не в этом дело. Им сама тема неинтересна, не имеет она к их жизни отношения. **Какое им дело до какого-то предложения?** Новый художественный метод? А, ну о'кей, пусть будет. Им, литературоведам, виднее, а нам-то что.

**Гоголя вот разбирают…** А я бы запретила изучать «Ревизора» в школе. Ничего, кроме неприязни, из школы не помню. Схемы, цитаты, сравнительные характеристики. Всю живую душу из произведения вынули. Дети еще не могут понять Гоголя – тонкий юмор, красоту слога. Да и  пьесу надо ставить, а не изучать, хотя бы отрывки. Вот весело было бы…

Да, но я же о предложении говорила, **а оно-то – знаковое!** Нельзя так писать. Просто убрали тире и кавычки – и вот уже новый метод изобрели? А на самом деле переступили черту, **нарушили границу прямой и косвенной речи.** Вот уж никогда такого не было! Со времен Пушкина, конечно, раньше-то я не помню.

**«Закон  личных местоимений»** – вот как надо его назвать, чтобы всем понятно было, да еще в Красную книгу занести. Что бы ни говорили, а это краеугольный камень правильного письма, без него стена обрушится и начнется анархия – ***олбанский язык*** в пунктуации. Знаки будут ставить на свой вкус, даже с намерением поставить неправильно. Эффектно же, и правил знать не надо!

Ну ладно, больше говорить не буду, и так много говорю. **Всё равно же никого нет**, кому слушать-то.

Comment: *раньше такого никогда не было.* — просто Вы этот вопрос не изучали. Почитали бы Бахтина (который Волошинов), увидели бы, как развивается взаимоотношение прямой и косвенной речи в языке, начиная ещё со "Слова о полку Игореве". Кстати, в самом "Слове" нет вообще ни одного случая косвенной речи. И что нам теперь — "обратно на деревья"? Нет, это не мой путь.

Comment: На деревья я Вас не зову, всё изучить невозможно, поэтому я и не собираюсь. К тому же знания желательно применять на практике, иначе изучать-то зачем. Меня же более всего интересует день сегодняшний, а не времена "Слова о полку Игореве". Я полагаю, что современные правила письма не должны ИНДИВИДУАЛЬНО ОБСЛУЖИВАТЬ все художественные поиски как писателей, так и литературоведов. Мне бы очень не хотелось, чтобы очевидно неправильно оформленная прямая речь была объявлена новой формой художественного самовыражения.

Comment: Что такое несобственно-прямая речь, я хорошо представляю. Вот могу для Вас какой-нибудь рассказик сочинить с такой речью, только тему задайте. Право же, мне незатруднительно будет. А хотите, что-нибудь из Толстого перепишу, с полным погружением в образ героя? (Вот для чего мне нужны знания, а всё остальное я считаю справочной информацией, которую легко найти в Сети.) Или можно у классиков поискать предложение с таким оформлением, как в том предложении, любопытно было бы взглянуть. Я-то ничего не изучала, а Вы, верно, знаете. Еще раз спасибо и, конечно же, извините мое невежество.

Comment: Язык нужен для взаимопонимания, а не для соблюдения оформительского формализма. У естественных языков есть только один закон: **всё, что помогает взаимопониманию — полезно, а всё, что мешает — вредно**. Других законов нет. Но есть правила, которые разрабатываются и улучшаются ради соблюдения этого закона. Ниже цитата из "Евгения Онегина", как её оформил Пушкин. Оформите её, пожалуйста, по всем правилам и Вы поймёте, почему от правил иногда нужно отступать. **— «Представь меня». — Ты шутишь. — «Нету». — Я рад. — «Когда же?» — Хоть сейчас. Они с охотой примут нас.**

Comment: Я работаю по Розенталю и других законов не знаю. С местоимениями здесь всё в порядке (о них в первую очередь шел разговор),  но  есть отклонения от правила в постановке кавычек. Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160  2. Если реплики следуют в подбор, без указания, кому они принадлежат, то каждая из них заключается в кавычки и отделяется от соседней тире:
«Так ты женат? Не знал я ране! Давно ли?» — «Около двух лет». — «На ком?» — «На Лариной». — «Татьяне?» — «Ты ей знаком?» — «Я им сосед» (П.).

Comment: У Пушкина в кавычки заключается речь только одного персонажа, вот и всё отклонение, что связано, очевидно, со стихотворной формой реплик, которые даются в подбор.. Это исключительный случай, который имеет объяснение и никому не мешает.

Comment: Это не просто "не мешает". Это даёт возможность читателю свободно, не сбиваясь, понимать, кто произносит каждую фразу этого рубленого диалога. Зачем Розенталь расставил кавычки по-своему? Он считает, что можно пожертвовать восприятием текста ради того, чтобы соблюсти формализм? Лучше бы он процитировал другого автора или хотя бы объяснил, почему он ставит кавычки, которых нет у Пушкина. Я такого не понимаю.

Comment: Это очень частный случай среди очень частных случаев, его можно не принимать во внимание. Здесь конфликт интересов: оформление прямой речи в подбор, то есть в одну строку, а строка не одна, потому что стихотворная. А в отдельную строку диалог оформляется с помощью тире, а не кавычек.  Вот и пришлось идти на вынужденный компромисс. Розенталю не надо было использовать этот пример, надо было поискать прозаический текст.  Но его можно извинить:  он просто не рассчитывал на такого придирчивого и внимательного читателя, как Вы, вот и поленился. А идеологии здесь нет никакой.

Comment: А может, он вообще разное оформление не заметил? Я эти кавычки только с третьего раза рассмотрела... И даже стала искать издание, где все кавычки будут на месте. Спасибо Вам большое, я теперь исправлюсь и буду очень, очень внимательным читателем.